# Company in one country full time employment in the other, EU citizen

Tags: work-environment

I have a question is it possible to be full time employee in one country and still run a company in the other one? 
I plan to work in Slovakia as a full time employee, however I still have company in Germany and I would like to keep it. Is it possible? I understand for company I pay tax in Germany and for the employment I pay tax in Slovakia?

Comment: What is the legal form of the company? Gmbh? Ag?

Comment: I kept a UK Limited (equivalent to GmbH) going when I worked in Germany for a few years. The UK company did not trade, but did file annual accounts at companies house. I don't see how it cold be a problem, but your account should be able to answer (an if you don't have an accountant, get one - it's the best investment you will ever make)

Comment: Check the details of your local tax laws, but I think (this isn't legal/financial advise) what you are proposing to do is OK from the point of view of 'is it legal' (I won't go into whether your employer would allow it or anything like that). However it probably isn't as simple as "for your company you pay tax in Germany and for your employment you pay tax in Slovakia" as that will depend on double taxation treaties, domicile, country of residence, etc. I would suggest you get hold of a financial adviser who has experience with 'international' issues like this.

Comment: Will you be hired as a company or as a private person?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I would be hired on full time position as a private person, and in the other country I still have my company which does conulting to the other company.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a question is it possible to be full time employee in one
>   country and still run a company in the other one? I plan to work in
>   Slovakia as a full time employee, however I still have company in
>   Germany and I would like to keep it. Is it possible?

The problem from the point of view of your employer is that they want you focused on your job. They don't want you working on your other business when they are paying you to do a job. They will want to know that you will not be using their time, and equipment to run the other business.

They will also want to know if you will have to periodically travel for the other business. If you will not be there when they need you they might not view you as a reliable employee.

They will want to know that your business is not a competitor. They also want to know that your won't be trying to sell the services of the other business to their employees, contacts and customers. They don't want a linkage between their corporate image and the other companies corporate image.

They are also concerned that their corporate intellectual property will be transferred to the other company. So they might be worried that they are paying you money to indirectly help the other business.

In many places the employer has specific rights over all the employees work products, and it can even extend to side-projects if there is a similarity between the side-project and the job.

You will have to be upfront with the employer during the negotiation, some will be ok with it, but some won't.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand you correctly that you are a consultant or a contractor, and you will be working for a new client/employer through a limited company?

If I understood you correctly, then answer is “it depends”:

- If you are on a short term contract, such as under 6 months, you can keep billing client from your original company.
- If you are on 6 months or longer contract, it might be difficult to continue doing it, since Slovakian tax authorities might argue that if you spend more than 183 days in a country – then you are tax resident in Slovakia, and might issue a bill including back taxes for the entire period.

That’s all very hypothetical though, – do check with accountants in both countries.

In my past, I had a similar situation I had a limited (GmbH) company in the UK and contract in Sweden. I worked through my UK company first 5 months, and then I registered a Swedish company and worked remaining time through Swedish company.